# Why my TensorFlow model is not changing their space after training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

After I load the saved model and fit new data, and save the model again then the disk space stays the same.

First of all, I check if the model exists in my dictionary. If models exist I load them from the folder and fit new data. After saving again, disk space doesn't change.

Here is my code:

```
    df = df[['y', 'h', 'o', 'l']]  
    df2 = df.values
 
    training = int(np.ceil(len(df) * .95)) 
    # prepere data for tensorflow
    # MinMaxScaler expecting like 1 feature
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df)
    print(f"scaled_data {len(scaled_data)}")

    # How many past days of data we want to use to predict the next day price
    prediction_days = 500
    train_data = scaled_data[0:int(training), :]
    print(f"train_data {len(train_data)}")
    # Preparing the Training data
    X_train = []
    y_train = []

    X_test = []
    y_test = []

    for x in range(prediction_days, len(train_data)):
        X_train.append(scaled_data[x - prediction_days:x, 0])
        y_train.append(scaled_data[x, 0])

        X_test.append(scaled_data[x - prediction_days:x, 0])
        y_test.append(scaled_data[x, 0])

    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
    X_test, y_test = np.array(X_test), np.array(y_test)

    # Reshaping so that it will work in Neural net
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
  

    print("Files")
    print(os.path.isfile('model.h5'))
    if os.path.isfile('model.h5') is False:
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(units=50))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(units=60))
        # define the optimization algorithm
        opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
        model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mean_squared_error')
        model.fit(X_train, y_train,  epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test)) #, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: 1e-8 * 10 ** (epoch / 30))]

        # evaluate the model

        model.save('model.h5') 
        model = load_model('model.h5')

        model_json = model.to_json()
        with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
            json_file.write(model_json)

        model.save_weights('model_weight.h5')
        model.load_weights('model_weight.h5')

    else:

        # load json and create model
        json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

        # load weights into new model
        model.load_weights("model.h5")
        print("Loaded model from disk")
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
        # train the model, iterating on the data in batches
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test)) # callbacks=[keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: 1e-8 * 10 ** (epoch / 30))]

        # check if model learning

        model_json = model.to_json()
        with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
            json_file.write(model_json)

        model.save_weights('model_weight.h5')
        model.load_weights('model_weight.h5')
```

And my model space look like this [image: IMG]

Comment: Why shouldn't the space stay the same? Every weight in the trained version also exists in the untrained version.

Comment: the model is parametric... what changes is the value of the attributes, not the number of attributes

Comment: Thank you both for explain @Alberto Sinigaglia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you **@Nick ODell** and **@Alberto Sinigaglia**. Mentioning these comments in the answer section for the community benefit.

> Every weight in the trained version also exists in the untrained
> version.
>
> the model is parametric... what changes is the value of the
> attributes, not the number of attributes